# Code compiles with clang but not with gcc

Tags: c++, gcc, clang

I have this piece of code that compiles fine with clang (even with -Weverything), but for which gcc issues an error.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

class PhonebookWriter
{
public:

  PhonebookWriter(const string& fname):
    fname_(fname), names_(), numbers_() {}

  PhonebookWriter& operator()(const string& name,
                  const string& number)
  {
    names_.push_back(name);
    numbers_.push_back(number);
    return *this;
  }

  ~PhonebookWriter(void)
  {
    ofstream f(fname_.c_str());
    for(size_t i=0;i<names_.size();++i)
      f << names_[i] << " " << numbers_[i] << "\n";
    f.close();
  }

private:
  const string fname_;
  vector<string> names_;
  vector<string> numbers_;
};

namespace {
  void write_guests_data(const string& fname)
  {
    PhonebookWriter(fname)("Mr Foo Bar","12345")("Mrs Bar Foo","54321");
  }
}

int main(void)
{
  write_guests_data("phone_book.txt");

  return 0;
}
```

and here's what I get when I try to compile the code:

```
$ g++ ./test.cpp
./test.cpp: In function ‘void {anonymous}::write_guests_data(const string&)’:
./test.cpp:39:27: error: declaration of ‘PhonebookWriter fname’ shadows a parameter
     PhonebookWriter(fname)("Mr Foo Bar","12345")("Mrs Bar Foo","54321");
                           ^
./test.cpp:39:48: error: no matching function for call to ‘PhonebookWriter::PhonebookWriter(const char [11], const char [6])’
     PhonebookWriter(fname)("Mr Foo Bar","12345")("Mrs Bar Foo","54321");
                                                ^
./test.cpp:39:48: note: candidates are:
./test.cpp:11:3: note: PhonebookWriter::PhonebookWriter(const string&)
   PhonebookWriter(const string& fname):
   ^
./test.cpp:11:3: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
./test.cpp:7:7: note: PhonebookWriter::PhonebookWriter(const PhonebookWriter&)
 class PhonebookWriter
       ^
./test.cpp:7:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
./test.cpp:39:49: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘(’ token
     PhonebookWriter(fname)("Mr Foo Bar","12345")("Mrs Bar Foo","54321");
                                                 ^
```

My gcc version is 4.9.1, and my clang version is 3.5.0.
I don't understand why there should even be a shadowing problem. Even if there were, it should have been picked up by clang.

Comment: Can you fix the shadowing problem so that both compilers are happy?  Or are you saying you don't understand the error message at all?

Comment: This is interpreted as `PhonebookWriter fname("Mr Foo Bar", "12345")` it seems, i.e. as the declaration of a local instance. You might work around it using a temporary or a named factory function, or even just a pair of brackets around the `PhonebookWriter(fname)`.

Comment: Yes, I can fix the shadowing problem in this specific example. However, I don't understand why there should be a problem in the first place, and also why different compilers respond differently to that code.

Comment: I was trying to avoid a temporary variable in the first place. Adding the extra brackets did the trick. Thanks.

Comment: Thread about the underlying issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28283215/gcc-or-clang-which-compiler-got-it-wrong

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change:

```
PhonebookWriter(fname)("Mr Foo Bar","12345")("Mrs Bar Foo","54321");
```

to:

```
(PhonebookWriter(fname))("Mr Foo Bar","12345")("Mrs Bar Foo","54321");
```

**EXPLANATION**

For some reason gcc removes the braces around `fname`, which turns the line into:

```
PhonebookWriter fname ("Mr Foo Bar","12345")("Mrs Bar Foo","54321");
```

And now the errors make sense.