# g++ rejects, clang++ accepts: foo(x)("bar")("baz");

Tags: c++, syntax, g++, clang++, most-vexing-parse

Somebody had [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28254915/code-compiles-with-clang-but-not-with-gcc/28255085) the other day why something compiles with clang, but not with gcc. I intuitively understood what was happening and was able to help the person, but it got me wondering -- according to the standard, which compiler was correct? Here is a boiled down version of the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class foo
{
public:
    foo(const std::string& x):
        name(x)
    { }
    foo& operator()(const std::string& x)
    {
        std::cout << name << ": " << x << std::endl;
        return (*this);
    }
    std::string name;
};

int main()
{
    std::string x = "foo";
    foo(x)("bar")("baz");
    return 0;
}
```

This compiles fine with clang++, but g++ gives the following error:

```
runme.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
runme.cpp:21:11: error: conflicting declaration ‘foo x’
    foo(x)("bar")("baz");
        ^
runme.cpp:20:17: error: ‘x’ has a previous declaration as ‘std::string x’
    std::string x = "foo";
```

If I add a pair of parentheses in line 21, g++ is happy:

```
(foo(x))("bar")("baz");
```

In other words, g++ interprets this line as:

```
foo x ("bar")("baz");
```

Methinks itsa bug in g++, but again, I wanted to ask the standard experts, which compiler got it wrong?

PS: gcc-4.8.3, clang-3.5.1

Comment: PPS: Tried it on [ideone](http://ideone.com/H9HKPT) with gcc-4.9.2 -- same error

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As far as I can tell this is covered in the draft C++ standard section `6.8` *Ambiguity resolution* which says that there can be an ambiguity between expression statements and declarations and says:

> There is an ambiguity in the grammar involving expression-statements
>   and declarations: An expression statement with a function-style
>   explicit type conversion (5.2.3) as its leftmost subexpression can be
>   indistinguishable from a declaration where the first declarator starts
>   with a (. In those cases the statement is a declaration. [ Note: To
>   disambiguate, the whole statement might have to be examined to
>   determine if it is an expression-statement or a declaration. This
>   disambiguates many examples. [ Example: assuming T is a
>   simple-type-specifier (7.1.6),

and gives the following examples:

```
T(a)->m = 7; // expression-statement
T(a)++; // expression-statement
T(a,5)<<c; // expression-statement

T(*d)(int); // declaration
T(e)[5]; // declaration
T(f) = { 1, 2 }; // declaration
T(*g)(double(3)); // declaration
```

and then says:

> The remaining cases are declarations. [ Example:
>
> ```
> class T {
>     // ...
>    public:
>     T();
>     T(int);
>     T(int, int);
> };
> T(a); // declaration
> T(*b)(); // declaration
> T(c)=7; // declaration
> T(d),e,f=3; // declaration
> extern int h;
> T(g)(h,2); // declaration
> ```
>
> —end example ] —end note ]

<s>It seems like this case falls into the declaration examples in particular the last example seems to make the case in the OP, so `gcc` would be correct then.</s>

Relevant section mentioned above `5.2.3` *Explicit type conversion (functional notation)* says:

> [...] If the type specified is a class type, the class type shall be complete. If the expression
>   list specifies more than a single value, the type shall be a class with a suitably declared constructor (8.5, 12.1),
>   and the expression T(x1, x2, ...) is equivalent in effect to the declaration T t(x1, x2, ...); for some
>   invented temporary variable t, with the result being the value of t as a prvalue.

and `8.3` *Meaning of declarators* which says:

> In a declaration T D where D has the form
>
> ```
> ( D1 )
> ```
>
> the type of the contained declarator-id is the same as that of the 
>   contained declarator-id in the declaration
>
> ```
> T D1
> ```
>
> Parentheses do not alter the type of the embedded declarator-id, but
>   they can alter the binding of complex declarators.

**Update**

I was originally using [N337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) but if we look at [N4296](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/blob/master/papers/n4296.pdf) section `6.8` was updated an it now includes the following note:

> If the statement cannot syntactically be a declaration, there is no ambiguity, so this rule does not
>   apply.

which means that `gcc` is incorrect since:

```
foo x ("bar")("baz");
```

can not be a valid declaration, I originally interpreted paragraph `2` as saying if you case begins with any of the following then it is declaration, which is perhaps how the `gcc` implementor interpreted as well.

I should have been more suspicious of paragraph `2` since the only normative part of paragraph `2` really said nothing with respect to paragraph `1` and seems to place a requirement on an example which is not normative. We can see that that statement form paragraph `2` is now actually a note which makes much more sense.

As T.C. noted below, paragraph `2` was actually never normative, it just appeared that way and he [linked to the change that fixed it](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/commit/4a58c6824c12ee4461edd9f5c891d050feca9032).

Comment: Thanks Shafik. Would creating a temporary `foo(x)` fall under _function-style explicit type conversion_? I shouldn't think so...

Comment: @InnocentBystander: No, I think it's a simple declaration.  It's parsed as `foo x;`

Comment: @InnocentBystander added more details from `5.2.3` which covers that.

Comment: Wouldn't the additional function call operation force the parse as a declaration to fail, and therefore choose the expression interpretation?

Comment: @BenVoigt I forgot to add the additional set of examples, I just added them and the last one seems identical to the OPs as far as I can tell.

Comment: @Steve similar but the most vexing parse is covered by section `8.2`

Comment: `T(g)(h,2);` is very different to `T(g)(h)(2);`

Comment: `foo(x)("bar")` is a valid declaration. `foo(x)("bar")("baz");` can't be.

Comment: @MattMcNabb I agree with you I have not been on SO for a long while after I answered but I realized later on that paragraph `2` seemed wrong and when I looked at `N4296` there were changes that made me realize I misinterpreted. I upvoted your answer as well. I wish I had a chance to update my answer earlier.

Comment: @T.C. agreed, I discovered my mistake when I looked at `N4296` I was not able to fix it until now.

Comment: @MattMcNabb, good catch. I've upvoted you as well. Shafik, thanks for updating the answer

Comment: 6.8p2 in N3337 isn't actually normative - though it looked that way. The paragraph started in the middle of a note. (The editorial change between N3337 and N4296/N4140 you cited was made [here](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/commit/4a58c6824c12ee4461edd9f5c891d050feca9032).)

Comment: @T.C. that makes more sense, thanks for finding that. BTW, how did you find that commit?

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour Blame.

Answer (score 5):

If we remove the line

```
std::string x = "foo";
```

then g++ complains about:

```
foo(x)("bar")("baz");
```

with the syntax error:

```
foo.cc:20:18: error: expected ',' or ';' before '(' token
     foo(x)("bar")("baz");
```

I do not see how `foo (x)("bar")("baz");` could be a valid declaration, and apparently g++ can't either.  The line `foo x("bar")("baz");` is rejected with the same error.

The "ambiguity resolution" mentioned in Shafik's post only kicks in when the expression-statement is syntactically indistinguishable from a declaration. However in this case it is not a valid declaration syntax so there is no ambiguity, it must be an expression-statement.

g++ fails to process the line as an expression-statement so it is a g++ bug.

This is eerily similar to [this g++ bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28034742/construction-of-temporary-in-function-call-is-interpreted-as-declaration/28035516#28035516) recently discussed on SO;  it seems that g++ is perhaps deciding too soon in processing that the line must be a declaration .