# Is "int (x), 1;" an ambiguous statement?

Tags: c++, syntax, expression, language-lawyer, variable-declaration

```
void f(int x) {
    int (x), 1;
}
```

Clang compiles it, GCC doesn't. Which compiler is correct?

Comment: Well, I guess it shouldn't.

Comment: You always have interesting questions.

Comment: Looks correct. But what is the point?

Comment: Wouldn't this error because it has no entry point defined?

Comment: I see no reason why this shouldn't compile. What error does gcc produce? Edit : It appears to complain that local `x` shadows the argument `x`. As far as I know, while this is a bad idea, it's allowed.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux This looks a lot like a declaration of `int x, <other declarations>`. And you are allowed extraneous parentheses in declarations

Comment: @Stephen Having a `void f() { ... }` has no problem compiling. If there's no main function anywhere, that will be a *linker* error. But compiling code that doesn't contain a main function is actually the common case

Comment: Similar to [g++ rejects, clang++ accepts: foo(x)(“bar”)(“baz”);](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28283215/1708801) ... this looks like it should be addressed by `Ambiguity resolution ` section

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: that's the point. Is that line a declaration, or an expression? Because I think clang compiles this, because it handles it as an expression.

Comment: Yeah it can also be seen as an expression: `int(x), 1` which is effectively `((int) x), 1`

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: You cannot redeclare a name within the same scope, only a nested scope.

Comment: @RegisPortalez: this is a stripped down example, so it may seem pointless, but it is not.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour: thanks, now I know where to look for answers: `stmt.ambig`. I've read this section three times, but still undecided. Maybe I need to re-read several times

Answer (score 18, accepted):

IMO, the wording in [[stmt.ambig]](http://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.ambig) is clear enough on this:

> **An *expression-statement*** with a function-style explicit type conversion as its leftmost subexpression **can be indistinguishable from a declaration where the first declarator starts with a `(`**. **In those cases** the statement is a declaration.
>
> [*Note*: **If the statement cannot syntactically be a declaration, there is no ambiguity, so this rule does not apply. The whole statement might need to be examined to determine whether this is the case.**

The wording speaks of an entire (expression-)statement.
Your statement cannot be parsed as a declaration, because the lexeme `1` is grammatically not a *declarator*. There is no ambiguity: it might look  ambiguous if we looked solely at `int(x)`, but the standard quite explicitly denies that if some prefix of the statement parses as a declaration, the entire statement is considered a potential declaration.

In fact, core experts had a highly similar discussion back in 2002 over [core issue 340](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_closed.html#340)---I highlighted the important bits. Here, again, we have a supposed declaration that contains an incompatible sub-construct.

> Consider the following program:
>
> ```
> struct Point   {
>   Point(int){}   
> };
> struct Lattice    {
>   Lattice(Point, Point, int){}   
> };
> int main(void)   {
>   int a, b;
>   Lattice latt(Point(a), Point(b), 3);   /* Line X */   
> }
> ```
>
> The problem concerns the line marked `/* Line X */`, which is an ambiguous
>   declarations for either an object or a function. The clause that
>   governs this ambiguity is 8.2 [dcl.ambig.res] paragraph 1, and reads:
>
> > The ambiguity arising from the similarity between a function-style
> >     cast and a declaration mentioned in 6.8 [stmt.ambig] [..]
>
> Based on this clause there are two
>   possible interpretations of the declaration in line `X`:
>
> - **The declaration of `latt` declares a function with a return value of the
>     type `Lattice` and taking three arguments. The type of the first two
>     arguments is `Point` and each of these arguments is followed by a
>     parameter name in redundant parentheses. The type of the third
>     argument can not be determined, because it is a literal.** This will
>     result in a syntax error.
> - The declaration of latt declares an object,
>     because the other option (a function declaration) would result in a
>     syntax error. Note that the last sentence before the "[Note:" is not
>     much help, because both options are declarations.
>
> **Steve Adamczyk: a number of people replied to this posting on
>   comp.std.c++ saying that they did not see a problem.**
>
> The original
>   poster replied:
>
> I can't do anything but agree with your argumentation. So there is
>   only one correct interpretation of clause 8.2 [dcl.ambig.res]
>   paragraph 1, but I have to say that with some rewording, the clause
>   can be made a lot clearer, like stating explicitly that the entire
>   declaration must be taken into account and that function declarations
>   are preferred over object declarations.
>
> I would like to suggest the following as replacement for the current
>   clause 8.2 [dcl.ambig.res] paragraph 1:
>
> > The ambiguity arising from the similarity between a functionstyle cast
> >     and a declaration mentioned in 6.8 [stmt.ambig] […]
>
> **The working group felt that the current wording is clear enough.**

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Now it's clear that clang is right. But, in my opinion, current wording should be improved. Because, it states at the end of 1: "In those cases the statement is a declaration." Then, the note tells, that this statement is not really always true, but only in the case when the statement can be syntactically a declaration. This can be a little bit confusing. End of 1 should read something like "In those cases, when the whole statement can be a syntactically correct declaration, then it is a declaration"